# How to better define selectors and events in module pattern?

Tags: jquery, module

As mentioned above, I use module pattern in javasript thus define selectors and events with namespace to prevent hardcoding.

However the list goes on and on as I have to define every single selectors and events being used this project. The main reason for doing this way is, in case I want to rename the selectors I can simply do it here where I define instead of searching for it throughout the module and fix it one by one.

**Is there better way of defining selectors with namespace or what I'm doing now is consider okay?**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 


});
```

Comment: typescript, and a better es6 approach . This helps with block scoping , and the import of classes

Comment: @gerdi, can you share some reference links please?

Comment: www.google.com , search es6 / es2015 and typescript . Might mean a lot of re writing though, that's why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: If it's working without errors, than it's *okay*